# Excel - Match, Lookup or Index

Tags: indexing, match, excel-2010, lookup

am sure this is an easy question but getting confused between all the formulas- `Lookup`, `Match`, `Index` etc.

I have 2 sheets - `SOW Actuals` and `RAW Project data`.

In column `N` of `SOW Actuals` I have the values I am trying to find in cells `A2:A60` of `Raw Project data`.
When the formula finds a value I want it to return the value from column `G` on the same row in `Raw Project data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INDEX` and `MATCH` are more efficient and flexible than `VLOOKUP`. In your case, try:

```
=INDEX('RAW Project Data'!$G$2:$G$60,MATCH('SOW Actuals'!$N1,'RAW Project Data'!$A$2:$A$60,0))
```

Comment: Thanks again Olly